# How to export csv file in adobe air?

Tags: air, adobe, export-to-csv

I am working on Adobe Air technology.

Getting some issue when i export CSV file into Chinese language, after exporting when i open it into Microsoft Office Excel sheet not getting records/data properly.I am using traditional Chinese language.

When i am using Kingsoft Office software (Excel sheet) got the correct result.

[image]

But when i use Microsoft Office getting random data like ?(question mark) signs.

[image]

IS there any language setting in Microsoft Office for set traditional Chinese language properly?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can export a csv from Office with a small set of test data(2 rows) then export same data from AIR then compare the files and see what is the difference.

Comment: can you post your code, it will help to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to export csv file as bytearray file using FileStream via writeMultiByte where you can setup your language charSet.

I had the same issue with Russian language.

Start from here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeMultiByte()

Don't afraid this bytes :) There is not more than 8-11 small lines of code.